# How to modify the TI SensorTag CC2650 Firmware to speed up data transfer?

Tags: performance, sensors

I'd like to modify the SensorTag Software from TI for the CC2650STK kit, so that it speeds up the reading and also the transmission of the sensor values.
Do I need to modify only the Sensor Software (CCS BLE Sensor stack from TI) or also the android app?

I'd principally need only one temperature, so other sub-question is: how can the other sensors be deactivated if not needed or if they conflict with the higher speed of the temperature sensor?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help]. Your question is somewhat broad, if not unclear. If you are able to share the code that you try to adapt the users might be better able to help you.

Comment: In which language is that software written that you intend to adapt? Also on speedup questions it helps if you can be precise about how much performance you need. *from 10 measurements per second I need it to go to at least 60 measurements per seconds*

Comment: Hi Rene, thanks for the comment. The software is the original CC2650 BLE Stack offered by TI, based on the CCS IDE and is wirtten in C++.
At the end, I'd need the maximum possible throughput with only one sensor, for example a temperature sensor.

Comment: Your question really needs code that demonstrates where you are now and what / how you want to improve: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14537347/578411

Comment: The component I'm referring to has a user Manual under http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC2650_SensorTag_User%27s_Guide
But it is not clear how one can speed up the sensor results.
My question is held open to anyone who has used this component or this kit or similar (older version) before, maybe facing the same challenges.
The source code comes with the Texas Instruments BLE Stack and can be directly downloaded from Code Composer Studio, also from TI.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "speeding up"?

There are a number of different things you might mean.

1. Reduce the latency between opening the mobile app and displaying a
   reading.
2. Refactor the mobile app to make it simpler to get new
   readings.
3. Increase the frequency with which notifications are sent
   by the device, if you use it in that way.
4. Change the firmware interaction with the sensors to obtain a reading.

Each of these meanings entails a different approach.

The period for each sensor is described in the User Guide that you reference and is typically between hundreds of milliseconds and one or two seconds. Do you really need readings more frequently than that?  Typically each sensor will need an amount of time in order to obtain a reliable reading.  This would be described in the sensor data sheet, along with options for working with the sensor.

More generally 'speed' will be a function of the bluetooth handshake, the throughput available over the physical radio link, the processing within the sensor tag and the processing within the sensors.  I would expect the most variable part of this would be the physical link.

It is up to the mobile app to decide which sensors services it wishes to use.

Have you studied the Software Developer's Guide, available at the same page as the BLE Stack?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the comment. 
You got the point. I think that actually all your listed aspects must eventually be treated at some point.
However, by "Speeding up", I mean principally the intervals between readings. I'm trying to achieve a sort of data streaming, with at least 250 packets per second. The packet should contain an X, Y, Z and an analog value.
At the moment. I'm trying to test if this is actually feasible with the available module, but I'm struggling to find the right "variables" or parameters to change in the stack/sample program.
Any hint? Thanks a lot